# Python API sentinelsat HTTP status 500 Internal Server Error:

Tags: python, download, sentinel1, sentinelsat

shows the error:
"HTTP status 500 Internal Server Error: Trying to download an offline product"
The code i am using is

```
import time
import datetime
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
api = SentinelAPI('*****','******', 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson('E:\map.geojson'))
products = api.query(footprint, date =('20161001' , '20170425'), platformname ='Sentinel-1', 
producttype = 'GRD')
api.download_all(products)
```

Comment: HTTP 500 is a server-side error message

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately this error is not due to `sentinelsat` api.

As error says, you are

> Trying to download an offline product.

You can download sentinel products that are online and not offline.

Sentinel products that are online are those of last 1 year, you are trying to download older products.

If you want an older product go to sentinel [scihub](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home) find a product, request it and it will be online later (could need 1 day or more, or if you are lucky a few hours later).